# Copy file, rename it, iterate and repeat

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, rename, file-rename

I use os.renmae to rename files and move them about, but i am failing at doing the following task.

I have a main folder containing sub-folders with the structure below.

Main folder "Back", containing sub-folders named with letters and numbers e.g. A01, A02, B01, B02, etc.. inside each of those folders is a set of files, amongst them is a file called "rad" so a file path example looks something like this:

Back/A01/rad
    /A02/rad
    /B01/rad
     .../rad

I have another sub-folder called "rads" inside the main "Back"
Back/rads

What i want to do is copy all the rad files only, from each of the folders in back and move them to the folder "rads" and name each rad file based on the folder it came from.
e.g. rad_A01, rad_A02, rad_B01, etc...

I couldnt really figure out how to increase the folder number when i move the files.

os.rename ("Back/*/rad, Back/rads/rad_*")

I thought of making a list of all the names of the files and then do something like from x in list, do os.rename (), but i didnt know how to tell python to name the file according to the subfolder it came from as they are not a continuous series..
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please note that i want to keep the original files where they are and not delete them after i copy which is why i didnt use shutil()

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk('./Back/'):
    for file in files:
        filepath = subdir+os.sep+file
        if filepath.endswith("rad.txt"):
            par_dir = os.path.split(os.path.dirname(filepath))[1]
            os.system('cp '+filepath+' ./Back/rads/rad_'+par_dir)
```

save this python file beside Back directory and it should work fine! 
This code iterates over each files in each subdirectory of Back, checks all files with name rad.txt, appends name of parent directory and copy to the rads folder.
Note: I saved rad files with .txt extension, change it accordingly.